# Boto3 access denied when calling the listobjects operation on a s3 bucket directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to access a bucket via cross account reference, the connection is established, but the put/list permissions are set on a specific directory (folder) i.e. bucketname/folder_name/*

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
 
    s3.upload_file("filename.csv","bucketname","folder_name/file.csv"
        ,ExtraArgs={'ACL':'bucket-owner-full-control'})
```

Not sure how do I allow the same via code, it throws access denied on both list/put. Nothing wrong with permissions as such, have verified the access via awscli, it works.
let me know if i'm missing something here, thanks!

Comment: What is the exactly the bucket policy?

Comment: What permissions are assigned to the IAM User / IAM Role being used, and what is the Bucket Policy on the bucket in the other account? The program will need at minimum `PutObject` and `PutObjectAcl` permissions

Comment: The permissions are correctly set, since i'm able to push files via awscli command, and list/ put both works that way. The bucket has PutObject, PutObjectAcl, GetObject permissions. My concern is with py script, I believe that 'upload_file' is checking permissions at the bucket level, while the user has access on the folder level. let me know if something's missing in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the assumed role, followed the documentation as mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html along with the code mentioned above.